# test browser supports the style or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can do the following to check if the browser doesn't support column-count css3 property then use my own code:

```
if (!('WebkitColumnCount' in document.body.style
        || 'MozColumnCount' in document.body.style
        || 'OColumnCount' in document.body.style
        || 'MsColumnCount' in document.body.style
        || 'columnCount' in document.body.style))
    {//my own code here}
```

But how can I check that background-image animation support?

This type of changing image source with css3 only works on chrome browsers.

```
0%{background-image: url(image-1);}
50%{background-image: url(image-2);}
100%{background-image: url(image-3);}
```

So, I wanted to know is there any technique that we can test that it is supported by the browser or not?

**Update**

I just tried like this code which is even not checking @keyframes style support:

```
if (('@keyframes' in document.body.style || '@-webkit-keyframes' in document.body.style))
{
   //if(!('from' in @keyframes || 'from' in @webkit-keyframes)){
   //code in here
   alert('test');
   //}
}
```

So even can I not test that @keyframes supported by browser or not?

---

**Solution:**

I've found from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations/Detecting_CSS_animation_support)

```
var animation = false,
    animationstring = 'animation',
    keyframeprefix = '',
    domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.split(' '),
    pfx  = '';

if( elm.style.animationName !== undefined ) { animation = true; }    

if( animation === false ) {
  for( var i = 0; i < domPrefixes.length; i++ ) {
    if( elm.style[ domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName' ] !== undefined ) {
      pfx = domPrefixes[ i ];
      animationstring = pfx + 'Animation';
      keyframeprefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
      animation = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Modernizer is really worth a look here , running this will add css class names to the `<html>` element based on what features are supported. ( not promoting third parties - good to write this/understand stuff ourselves, but I felt worth a mention - http://modernizr.com/

Comment: anyway if I find the js solution, I'll be very happy.

Comment: I often confuse (difficult) to use modernizr.

Comment: if you test for 'animation' you are also testing for support of `@keyframes` - `@keyframe` is a 'rule' not a 'style'

Answer (score 0):

As well as the mention to **[modernizer](http://modernizr.com/download/)** in the comments - we could first add in the **[vendor prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation)** for the background animations to get more browser coverage. like :

```
#animationdivTest { 
   animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
   -ms-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
}
```

*I'm guessing at what animation you are doing*

---

A blunt check for this in javascript might be

```
/* check a doc.fragment div or test div on page */
var el = document.getElementById('animationdivTest');
/* create a function here to test for ALL the vendor prefixes 
( this is where modernizer comes in v handy )

 one example - */
if( el.style['-webkit-animation'] !== undefined ) {
   document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className +=' cssanimation'; 
}
```

Our Css can then be tailored :

```
.cssanimation #animationdiv { 
       animation: animatedBackground ...
```

---

We can have a live play here - http://jsbin.com/yamepucu/1/edit

Not sure how much that helps vrs what you already know , hope some part did.

---

### **Update:** showing how testing for `style.animation` can be combined with the check for `style.background-image` ( *checking for background-image tells us whether the @keyframes have been applied* )

### [Try live demo](http://jsbin.com/hinidape/1/edit)

**HTML**

```
  <div id="animationdivTest">Testing...</div>
  <div id="animationdiv"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes bgAnimation {
  0% {
    background-image: url('http://www.new4.co.uk/flip/flip-3.gif');
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url('http://www.new4.co.uk/flip/flip-2.gif');
  }
  70% {
    background-image: url('http://www.new4.co.uk/flip/flip-1.gif');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('http://www.new4.co.uk/flip/flip-0.gif');
  }

}

#animationdivTest, .cssbgAnimation #animationdiv {

  width: 90px;
  height: 240px;
  -webkit-animation-name: bgAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

#animationdiv:after { content:"Sorry not supported"; }  
.cssbgAnimation #animationdiv:after { content:""; }
.cssbgAnimation #animationdivTest { position:absolute; left:-999px; top:-9999px; }
```

**Example JS** *added in a function loop to check for the other vendor prefixes this time*.

```
var el = document.getElementById('animationdivTest');
function hasBgAnimSupport() {
  var does =false, 
  animVendorprefixes = ['animation','-ms-animation','-moz-animation','-webkit-animation'];

  for(i=0, len = animVendorprefixes.length; i<len; ++i) {
    if( el.style[animVendorprefixes[i]] !== undefined ) { 
      if( el.style['background-image'] !== undefined ) {
        does=true; break;
      }
    }
  }
  return does;
 } 


if(hasBgAnimSupport() ) { 
   document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className +=' cssbgAnimation';
}
```

AFAIK - this is the closest and future proof way we can check for this

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But it is still not  checking that background-image animation support or not! It is just checking the animation property.

Comment: nope! you understood my question mistakenly. I just wanted to test background-image animation which only runs on chrome. please re-read the question.

Comment: if you are so sure - then just 'test for chrome' - OR there is a wider browser way to do the animation - show us what you mean in demo and i'll see what you mean ( your q only has partial css )

Comment: I shouldn't test it only for chrome browser because it may be added in future.

Comment: you should see in my question 0%{.... contains background-image src changing which is supported by chrome but not with firefox.

Comment: "I shouldn't test it only for chrome browser because it may be added in future" - exactly - but your q only tests for *some* of the vendor prefixes ....

Comment: Yeah, I was just testing and said even it is not working and you can see in my testing with comment lines what I was trying.

Comment: `@keyframes` is not a 'style' so it would never run into the 'comments'

Comment: Hi @C-link, updated - might be more in line with what you are after