# How to overwrite CSS3 keyframes using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to overwrite the values in Keyframes using JQuery

Here my Code:

```
.v5Container { 
    background: #ffffff; 
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    z-index: 101; 
    animation: 2s linear 0s normal none 1 formAnimate;
}
 @keyframes formAnimate {
    0% {transform: rotateY(-90deg); opacity:0;}
    100% {transform: rotateY(0deg); opacity:1;}
}
```

I want to overwrite this `rotateY()` and `opacity` value using JQuery.

Comment: And where is your jQuery code?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402603/test-browser-supports-the-style-or-not

Comment: @panther I don't know how to overwrite in JQuery, thatsy i asked

Answer (score 0):

There is this:
[Set Webkit Keyframes Values Using Javascript Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342494/set-webkit-keyframes-values-using-javascript-variable) In the fiddle included in his answer - you can see how to get the CSS-Keyframe and change it.

Maybe a better solution: [programmatically changing webkit-transformation values in animation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105530/programmatically-changing-webkit-transformation-values-in-animation-rules)